# Access to a param in another controller sended by render :template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, render

So im sending a param from a view to a view of another controller

```
<%= render template: 'dishes/new', :id => @restaurant.id %>
```

and this is my other controller view:

```
  def new
    @dish = Dish.new
     @id = params[:id]
  end

  def create
    @dish = Dish.new(dish_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dish.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'dish was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: :restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'show', location: :restaurant  }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
  def dish_params
    params.require(:dish).permit( :avatar, :name, :description, [:id])
  end
```

and this is my view who calls the form:

```
#new.html.erb
<h1>Add a new dish</h1>

<%= render 'dishes/dish_form' %>
```

then here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @dish, :url => { :controller => "dishes", action_name => "create" } do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dish_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Add new dish' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but when i try to save it i got this error:
[image: error]

Comment: action `show` no exist in your controller

Comment: yeah i know i will solve that issue later, the problem is entering there because there is no restaurant id

Comment: You call `@restaurant` in `create` action but `@restaurant` not defined.

Comment: you are not getting my problem :/, im conscious of that problem but is not my issue right now, its missing the id that im sending in the render

Comment: can you show us, where you define a `@restaurant` variable so that you call `@restaurant` on `create` action?

Comment: i think i put the wrong image, the @restaurant is defined in my other controller named Restaurant which have the show def where i send `<%= render template: 'dishes/new', :id => @restaurant.id %>`, then in my dishes controller, inside of my create def i have `@dish.restaurant_id = params[:id]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes in when you are expecting your `render template: 'dishes/new'` to hit your `DishesController`. That is not what is happening when you are calling the render.

What you're doing is telling rails to load into your current view the template for `'dishes/new'`, and you're passing `'dishes/new'` a variable that it can access when rendering. You aren't sending a param to a controller.

If you want to keep the current set up you have right now, you can make it work with some tweaking.

I'm going to assume that your `Dish` model belongs to `Restaurant`, and therefore has `restaurant_id` as a column. If that is true, then you can add a hidden field to your form for dishes, called `restaurant_id`, and update your permitted params in your controller to allow the restaurant id to be set on the dish.

Your form would look like this:

```html
<%= form_for @dish, :url => { :controller => "dishes", action_name => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, value: id %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Your permitted params in your controller would look like this:

```rb
def dish_params
  params.require(:dish).permit(:avatar, :name, :description, :restaurant_id)
end
```

You can get more information on how the rails rendering is working [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: thats what i do and works! but i use this line
`<%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, value: params[id] %>`
cause i already getting the param, i try to put `@id = params[:id]` in the create controller of Dishes and use `<%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, value: @id %>` but didnt work, it only works with the first

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that your controller named Restaurants does not have an action named "Show".

One solution would be to add the Action with the name "Show" to the restaurant controller.

The other option may be that you actually created the action you wanted, but you named it something other than "Show".

Comment: yeah but its entering in the else because it dont detect the restaurant id that im sending in the render